# Azure Table Storage - TableEntity map column with a different name

Tags: azure, mapping, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using Azure Table Storage as my data sink for my Semantic Logging Application Block. When I call a log to be written by my custom `EventSource`, I get columns similar to the ff.:

- EventId
- Payload_username
- Opcode

I can obtain these columns by creating a `TableEntity` class that matches the column names exactly (except for `EventId`, for some reason):

```
public class ReportLogEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string Payload_username { get; set; }
    public string Opcode { get; set; }
}
```

However, I would like to store the data in these columns in differently named properties in my `TableEntity`:

```
public class ReportLogEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; } // maps to "EventId"
    public string Username { get; set; } // maps to "Payload_username"
    public string Operation { get; set; } // maps to "Opcode"
}
```

Is there a mapper/attribute I can make use of to allow myself to have the column name different from the `TableEntity` property name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override [ReadEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.readentity.aspx) and [WriteEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.writeentity.aspx) methods of interface [ITableEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.aspx) to customize your own property names.

```
    public class ReportLogEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; } // maps to "EventId"
        public string Username { get; set; } // maps to "Payload_username"
        public string Operation { get; set; } // maps to "Opcode"

        public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = properties["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
            this.RowKey = properties["RowKey"].StringValue;
            this.Id = properties["EventId"].StringValue;
            this.Username = properties["Payload_username"].StringValue;
            this.Operation = properties["Opcode"].StringValue;
        }

        public override IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>();
            properties.Add("PartitionKey", new EntityProperty(this.PartitionKey));
            properties.Add("RowKey", new EntityProperty(this.RowKey));
            properties.Add("EventId", new EntityProperty(this.Id));
            properties.Add("Payload_username", new EntityProperty(this.Username));
            properties.Add("Opcode", new EntityProperty(this.Operation));
            return properties;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that at least with WindowsAzure.Storage 8.1.1, adding the PartitionKey/RowKey to the properties dictionary in WriteEntity will cause an exception for duplication. I'm assuming they are now being added for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataMember` attribute for this:

```
public class ReportLogEntity : TableEntity
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "EventId")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "Payload_username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "Opcode")]
    public string Operation { get; set; }
}
```